# Alphabetically ordered binary tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I have to write some code that automatically adds words to a binary tree in alphabetic order. I know I have to put in loops and more if statements, I just don't know where.
If the word is alphabetically smaller it should go to the left, otherwise to the right.

This is my code so far:

```
struct node
{
  string info;
  node* right;
  node* left;
}; //closes node

class States
{
 private:
  node* start;

 public:
  void insert();
  void delete();
  void list();
  void search();
  States();
}; //closes States class

States::States()
{
  start = new node;
  start -> left = NULL;
  start -> right = NULL;
  start -> info = ' ';
}
void States::insert()
{
  string state;
  char c;
  node *temp, *p, *s;
  p = start;
  s = start;
  cout<<"Please enter the state you want to add: ";
  cin>>state;

  if(s -> info == ' ')
    {
      s -> info = state;
      cout<<"Added state "<<state<<"to the list.\n";
      cout<<"Ready to continue? (enter y)";
      cin>>c;
      return;
    }//close if
 else
    {
      temp = new node;
      temp ->info = state;

      if(s->info > temp->info)
        {
          p = p-> left;
          if(
          p = s -> left;

        }//close if

    }//close else

}//close insert function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the loop. This code is somewhat close, and you can almost get away with adding just a `while(true) {}` loop around the if/else in the insert method.

But you're going to run into some issues with cases where a user enters the same state more than once (> is false, but do you want to go the other direction). Or what if a user enters ' '. You'll want to add some error checking to your insert method.

You also probably don't want to be recreating the temp node each time you enter the else--you're going to be creating (I think) d-1 (where d = the depth of your tree) extra nodes each time you insert something.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me and I got it to work, now I'm at my next problem, the alphabetical listing of all the states.

Comment: That seems to be pretty straightforward. Assuming the left most node will be your first state, it's just going to be a left-to-right traversal of your tree. This can be decomposed into the traversal of sub trees with either a recursive algorithm or a loop.